# How do I replace text in a span element using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the #percent amount to change to the text contained in the li that is clicked. Someone help me fix my code please and thanks!

```
<div id="percentchooser">
<ul>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li class="selectedpercentage">35</li>
    <li>40</li>
    <li>45</li>
    <li>50</li>
</ul>
<div id="percentage"><span id="percentamount">35</span><span id="percentsign">%</span>

</div>
```

```
$("#percentchooser li").click(function () {

    var percentage = $(this).html();

    $("#percentchooser li").removeClass("selectedpercentage");
    $(this).addClass("selectedpercentage");

    $("#percentageamount").html(percentage);


});
```

Comment: That should work fine. Horrifically inefficiently, but otherwise fine.

Comment: See jQuery `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to reference the wrong id, the id of the span is `percentamount` in your HTML example but you are referencing it as `percentageamount` in the script:

```
$("#percentchooser li").click(function () {
    var percentage = $(this).html();

    $("#percentchooser li").removeClass("selectedpercentage");
    $(this).addClass("selectedpercentage");

    $("#percentamount").html(percentage);
});
```

Ones changed it seems to work.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu7cc/) - Using `#percentamount` instead

---

Comment: Thanks, it always helps having someone else look at it. silly mistake.. I thought I knew what I was doing..

Answer (score 0):

i dont see any percentage amount id here, so i guess this should work

```
   $("#percentamount").html(percentage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not using jQuery? It is unnecessary in this situation:

```
(function() {
  var chooser = document.getElementById('percentchooser'),
      selected = (function() {
        var li = chooser.children[0].children, len = li.length, i;
        for(i=0;i<l;i++) if(li[i].className == "selectedpercentage") return li[i];
      })(), target = document.getElementById('percentamount');
  chooser.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if( !t.tagName) t = t.parentNode; 
    if( t.tagName.toLowerCase() == "li") {
      selected.className = "";
      t.className = "selectedpercentage";
      target.firstChild.nodeValue = t.firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
  };
})();
```